# DO multiple rstudio sessions access different workspaces?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am running multiple sessions of Rstudio on my local machine.

- Is the workspace for each session common across sessions?
- Should I worry about making inadvertent edits to say the workspace from session 1 by making changes in session 2?

If it helps, this is a Windows machine.

Comment: Yes. Each studio has its own R session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each studio has its own R session:

[image]

Comment: That's a screenshot from process explorer https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx. showing two `rstudio` running, each having started its own `rsession`